# Should we Dispose images of buttons before form close in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, image, forms, button, memory

Is it important to dispose of images or backgrounds of buttons or any other control in a form before we call `Form.Close`?  Do we need to do that in order to avoid memory problems?

The form is being shown with the `Show` method, not the `ShowDialog` method.

Comment: Can you show how you create/use images for the controls/

Comment: it's by From designer, not by me

Comment: Images are **not** automatically disposed.  You'll get away with that for the kind of small image you'd use for a Button.Image, the garbage collector will get around to it.  But it is much harder to ignore for a BackgroundImage or a PictureBox.Image, they tend to be large.

Answer (score 0):

Once a form is closed and disposed all UI elements on that form will be disposed as well.

Comment: really that gets me crazy ! so why when i test my application and make a timer to show a form every second, the memory in (private KB) in resources monitor keep growing up and reach 1000 MB after little time?

Comment: I removed all codes that are running when form load, i just left the form controls to be loaded. what's the problem ?

Comment: you make a timer to do what?I am not getting clearly what your are saying

Comment: i made a timer to show and close a form in my application , that's in order to discover if there is a memory problem, so when i did that , the allocated memory for my application was growing up constantly and never releases , it reached 1 GB by the time ! That's the problem